# Strange behavior from pandas .agg in a time-series

Tags: pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I am using financial data from yfinance.

```
import yfinance as yf
df = yf.download("AAPL", interval="5m", period="60D")
```

The data-frame looks like this:

```
                                 Open        High
Datetime                                         
2021-09-14 09:30:00-04:00  150.929993  151.054993
2021-09-14 09:35:00-04:00  150.279999  150.820007
2021-09-14 09:40:00-04:00  150.360001  150.619995
2021-09-14 09:45:00-04:00  150.327698  150.619995
2021-09-14 09:50:00-04:00  150.100006  150.190002
2021-12-07 15:35:00-05:00  170.274994  170.279999
2021-12-07 15:40:00-05:00  170.038101  170.250000
2021-12-07 15:45:00-05:00  170.229996  170.300003
2021-12-07 15:50:00-05:00  170.279999  170.750000
2021-12-07 15:55:00-05:00  170.699997  171.270004
```

I want to run a custom lambda function in the aggregation along with other functions.

```
df.groupby(df.index.normalize()).agg({"High": (lambda x: len(x))})
```

Just this experiment returns zero as the length. This is not the case in regular data-frames.

Answer (score 1):

Tested and for me working correct:

```
import yfinance as yf
df = yf.download("AAPL", interval="5m", period="60D").iloc[[11,2000,2001,2002,203,204,205, 206]]
print (df)

df = df.groupby(df.index.normalize()).agg({"High": (lambda x: len(x))})
print (df)
                           High
Datetime                       
2021-09-14 00:00:00-04:00   1.0
2021-09-16 00:00:00-04:00   4.0
2021-10-19 00:00:00-04:00   3.0
```

Comment: Update from 1.3.1 to 1.3.4 fixed it for me as well.